# Wordpress Apache Config Errors

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have installed Wordpress on Apache. It appears to work fine, i get the homepage and have created pages on the admin.

I can access the home[page fine. But when i try access the pages. I get 404s.

http://mysite.com/ works fine

http://mysite.com/news throughs a 404.

In the log files, I have the following error:

[Fri Dec 14 10:21:58 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/wordpress/mysite/news, referer: http://mysite.com/

I am using NameBasedVirtual hosting in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/wordpress/mysite/

    ErrorLog /var/log/www/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/www/mysite-access.log combined

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
          SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /home/wordpress/mysite>
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>

    <Location /wp-admin/>
        Header set Cache-Control no-cache
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you enabled permalinks? What does the .htaccess file look like?

Comment: htaccess file has not been changed. Its the default. yes, permalinks enabled.

Comment: Your tip helped. i looked at .htaccess. It says <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>. But Apache doesnt have mod_rewrite installed by default on Ubuntu. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I looked at .htaccess.

It says .

But Apache doesnt have mod_rewrite installed by default on Ubuntu. So it didnt work and didnt through a nice error.

Just add in mod_rewrite to fix this